# Can't set content type from using uploadFile method in @azure/storage-blob (SDK/NPM)

Tags: node.js, azure, content-type, azure-blob-storage

Can't set azure content type from node using below code. It's always storing content type as octane stream.

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const { AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING } = process.env;

let blobServiceClient;

async function getBlobServiceClient() {
  if (!blobServiceClient) {
    blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
  }

  return blobServiceClient;
}

async function uploadFile(filePath, containerName) {
  const bsClient = await getBlobServiceClient();
  const containerClient = bsClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('myImag6.png', { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } });

  try {
    const res = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The following issue seems related to this but I am not sure.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/6192

Please give me more info on this and how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you need to set content type, please add ```{ blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } }``` in the ```uplaodFile``` method. The ```getBlockBlobClient``` have no way to set it. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerclient?view=azure-node-latest#getblockblobclient-string- and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadfile-string--blockblobparalleluploadoptions-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try setting the blobHttpHeaders and passed to the uploadFile method?

```
const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } };
const res = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath, blobOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose it's because you don't set the `BlockBlobUploadOptions` in the `uploadFile` method, you only use it in the `getBlockBlobClient` method, in my below code test, it could set the content type.

```
    const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

    // Enter your storage account name and shared key
    const account = "account name";
    const accountKey = "account key";

    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      sharedKeyCredential
    );

    const containerName = "test";

    async function main() {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);


  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('test.txt');
  const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'text/plain' } };
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile('E:\\project\\jsstorage\\test.txt',blobOptions);

  console.log(`Upload block blob test.txt successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
}

main();
```

[image]